# how generate gstring from a multiple string in groovy?

Tags: groovy, gstring

Im trying to generate gstring from this code but not works

```
date="01"


varzcx= "\${"+"date" +"}";
println  varzcx
```

this print ${date}

I need print 01

please help me

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: but this code works Im using groovy

Comment: .this code works    .

Comment: So if it works then what are you doing asking this question?

Comment: but print other result

Comment: print ${date}  is a string not gstring

Comment: So it doesn't work?

Comment: yes but i need variable string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166065/discussion-between-grant-garrison-and-mightguy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this...

```
date="01"
varzcx= "\${"+"date" +"}";
println  varzcx
```

You probably want this...

```
date="01"
varzcx= "${date}"
println varzcx
```